# How to use AddProblemDetails extension in class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-7.0

I want to write custom extension using brand new Asp.Net Core 7.0 [AddProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.problemdetailsservicecollectionextensions.addproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-7.0) extension in class library.

I tried to add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/) and [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) nuget packages, but that didn't help. What package reference should I include to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the ASP.NET Core shared framework in a [class library project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) - add `FrameworkReference` element for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```